# AO bakes then disappears at the end of the baking cycle

Tags: texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

This is not a question about Black AO or no AO. I'm posting a resolution for a somewhat unique problem (?) I had where my ***AO bake proceeded normally, but then simply disappeared at the end of the bake cycle***.

Sharing my root cause in case someone sees the same issue (can't believe I'm the only one :))

This assumes that you are doing all the right things in terms of setting up the image in the ShaderEditor, Normals are good, no hidden objects blah blah -- lots of posts on those checklist items, so won't repeat.

My repro case:

1. A collection with many objects
2. Bake AO
3. You should see the bake progressing normally...AO being baked to the image
4. At the end of the cycle the AO that you could see in the image, simply disappears
5. No errors
   Result: blank no-more-AO image!

The cause:  Its hidden object related, but not actually one hidden.

One of my objects was in fact, not an object at all.

At some point, I must have deleted the objects vertices, so there is no more mesh, but I did not delete the actual Object in the outliner itself. After I removed the object from the render (camera icon), the bake then "stayed"!

I figured this out through a process of elimination which took a looong time (the dang object was one of the last objects in my collection list :)), but a faster way to do this ***AND PERHAPS this is where someone can add a better method***) was to go into object mode, and click though each object in the list in that collection to make sure you can actually "see" that is has Mesh (and not just an origin point) in the viewport!!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that it's blanking the AO image, and not just changing the actively selected image in the image editor at the end of the bake?

Comment: Pretty sure that's not happening for 2 reasons: 1) I have only one image Texture I'm baking AO to in the material (just a BSDF and the image texture -- nothing complicated), so not sure what you mean by "changing the actively selected image" ?.. but more importantly 2) if the ONLY thing I do is to unselect that no-mesh object from the render, the AO bakes completes. If its included, then I see the behavior described (can see baking happening, but then AO disappears to be replaced with just Black).

Comment: I would have to see a file to see if I could reproduce the problem.  Set up so I just hit bake to reproduce it.